# React: Updating form on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have three components, App, TextBox and Keyboard.

What I am trying to do is:

1. User clicks on one of the buttons on keyboard.jsx, a child component
2. Pass the associated character to App.js (this works, via callback functions)
3. Once a new character has been passed to App.js, update the other child component, TextBox.jsx, by passing it the new value.

However, I am stuck at step 3. I have the value passed to App.js, but I don't know how to pass it to the child component, Keyboard.jsx,  so i can update the input form.

Here is my code:

keyboard.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Keyboard extends Component {
  state = {
    current: null,
    keys: ["á", "é", "í", "ñ", "ó", "ú", "ü"]
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            {Object(
              this.state.keys.map(key => {
                return (
                  <td>
                    <button
                      onClick={() => {
                        this.solve(key, this.props.handler);
                      }}
                    >
                      {key}
                    </button>
                  </td>
                );
              })
            )}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
  solve = (char, callback) => {
    this.setState({ current: char });
    callback(char);
    return;
  };
}

export default Keyboard;
```

textbox.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class TextBox extends Component {
  state = { equation: null };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.mySubmitHandler}>
          <input
            size="35"
            type="text"
            name="equation"
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
  handleInputChange = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };

  mySubmitHandler = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ equation: event.target.value });
    alert("You are submitting " + this.state.equation);
    console.log(this.state.equation);
  };
}

export default TextBox;
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import Keyboard from "./components/keyboard";
import TextBox from "./components/textbox";

class App extends Component {
  state = { character: null };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TextBox />
        <Keyboard handler={this.handler} />
      </div>
    );
  }

  handler = arg => {
    console.log(arg);
  };
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You don’t seem to be using props?

Comment: I am not sure what are you doing here, but passing your arg as a prop to TextBox will do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I see you are trying to do is to have buttons with certain special letter that you can click to insert them into a input field that is in a separate component.

In this particular case you should implement two-way binding. It'll work like this:

```js
class Keyboard extends React.Component {
  state = {
    current: null,
    keys: ["á", "é", "í", "ñ", "ó", "ú", "ü"]
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            {Object(
              this.state.keys.map(key => {
                return (
                  <td>
                    <button
                      onClick={() => {
                        this.solve(key, this.props.handler);
                      }}
                    >
                      {key}
                    </button>
                  </td>
                );
              })
            )}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
  solve = (char, callback) => {
    this.setState({ current: char });
    callback(char);
    return;
  };
}

class TextBox extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.mySubmitHandler}>
          <input
            value={this.props.equation}
            size="35"
            type="text"
            name="equation"
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
  handleInputChange = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
    this.props.equationChange(event.target.value)
  };

  mySubmitHandler = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("You are submitting " + this.props.equation);
    console.log(this.props.equation);
  };
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { character: null };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TextBox equationChange={this.equationChange} equation={this.state.equation} />
        <Keyboard handler={this.handler} />
      </div>
    );
  }

  handler = arg => {
    console.log(arg);
    this.setState({ equation: (this.state.equation || '') + arg
                  });
  };

  equationChange = equation => {
    this.setState({ equation });
  }
}

React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

A working codepen: https://codepen.io/leo-melin/pen/mdyEvwQ

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by passing the state variable character `this.state.character` to the child component `Textbox` in `App.js`, and `this.handler` method in `App.js` should update the `this.state.character`.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = { character: null };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TextBox character={this.state.character} />
        <Keyboard handler={this.handler} />
      </div>
    );
  }

  handler = arg => this.setState({ character: arg });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass this.state.character as prop to textbox and then in textbox.jsx extract character from props i.e  `const {character} = this.props` and then display it in textbox.